# How to add string at the end of existing string in VB

Tags: vb.net, string-concatenation

I have a string `Str1` and I wish to add new string `Str2` at the end of `Str1`

My code is:

```
Dim TmpMsgGSM As String
Dim ind1 =-1
TmpMsgGSM = "CONFigure:GSM:SIGN"

ind1 = TmpMsgGSM.IndexOf("SIGN")
ind1 = ind1 + 3
TmpMsgGSM.Insert(TmpMsgGSM.IndexOf("SIGN") + ind1, "koko")
```

I get exception at the line where I use `Insert`.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: As an aside, you need to re-assign the return value of `String.Insert` to the `String` variable since strings are immutable(cannot be modified).

Comment: Why not simply: `Dim str = TmpMsgGSM &  "koko"`

Comment: What is the exception? It might tell you all you need to know.

Comment: Yes I try the & now ...

Comment: Can I use String.Concat(value1, value2) and if yes what is the benefit

Comment: `x & y` is short-hand for `String.Concat(x, y)`. They both compile to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the problem with your code:

```
Dim TmpMsgGSM As String
Dim ind1 =-1
TmpMsgGSM = "CONFigure:GSM:SIGN"

ind1 = TmpMsgGSM.IndexOf("SIGN")
ind1 = ind1 + 3 '17
'TmpMsgGSM.IndexOf("SIGN") + ind1 = 14 + 17 = 31
TmpMsgGSM.Insert(TmpMsgGSM.IndexOf("SIGN") + ind1, "koko")
```

The expression `TmpMsgGSM.IndexOf("SIGN") + ind1` has a value of `31` - that's way past the end of the string `TmpMsgGSM` Hence the exception.

If you just do `TmpMsgGSM.Insert(ind1, "koko")` then you get the string `"CONFigure:GSM:SIGkokoN"` out. You probably need to add `4` to `ind1` rather than `3` to get `"CONFigure:GSM:SIGNkoko"`.

But, of course, the easy way to do this is `TmpMsgGSM = TmpMsgGSM & "koko"`.

Even better is `TmpMsgGSM &= "koko"`.